# Android: saving a Firebase push notification to disk when the app is not running or in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, background, gson

I'm having problems saving some obj i create starting from FireBase push notification system to disk using GSon library.

**What I want to do:** 
When a push notification is received, an obj is created, added to a container and saved to disk. It will be read and used by the GUI to create a facebook like notifications list.
**Only** if the app is not running or is in background, a notification icon is also shown in the tray.

**What I already have:**
All works if the app is running in foreground. If the app is not running or is in background, the notification icon appears on tray, but no saving is performed, and when i open the app, nothing is displayed in the GUI.

Here's my onMessageReceived from FireBase

```
    @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    NotificationsContainer notificationsContainer;

    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        PixNotifications.sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()); //Here the app show the icon in system tray, only if it's running in background.
    }

    notificationsContainer = Utilities.readNotificationsFromDisk(); //Read actual container from disk
    if(notificationsContainer == null){ //No container?
        notificationsContainer = new NotificationsContainer(); //Create an empty one
    }

    try{
        Notification notification = new Notification(remoteMessage); //Create a displayable notification
        notificationsContainer.pushNotification(notification); //Put it in the container
        Utilities.saveNotificationsToDisk(notificationsContainer); //Save container to disk
        PixideCore.getInstance().reloadNotificationsContainerContent(); //Reload container in PixideCore
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification save to disk error");
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As FCM mentioned in their [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) when your app is in the background the function  of ***OnMessageReceived*** in your service will not be called int the first place.

---

> Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app
>
> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages > to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher
> by default.
>
> This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload
> (and all messages sent from the Notifications console). In these cases,
> the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data > payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher
> Activity.

---

Knowing that there is a rather simple solution to change the notification structure and remove the notification info and pass it in the data  part of the Remote Message.

Unfortunately  for me this solution will not suffice since I can't change the all data structure in the place I work at, but I will be sure to remember that in the future.